# In the United States, coins have certain thicknesses. If a stack of these coins is exactly $14$ mm high, how many coins are in the stack?

Tags: contest-math, arithmetic

> In the United States, coins have the following thicknesses: penny, $1.55$ mm; nickel, $1.95$ mm; dime, $1.35$ mm; quarter, $1.75$ mm. If a stack of these coins is exactly $14$ mm high, how many coins are in the stack?

Adding an odd number of coins results in $5$ being in the hundreth place and adding two coins results in odd number in the tenth place and $0$ in the hundreth place.

Now from this they have made a conclusion that the only way the sum of these thicknesses can have $0$'s in it's tenth and hundreth place must be a multiple of $4$. Where does this fact originate from?

Comment: You need an even number of coins to have a zero in the hundredths place. This carries a 1. So the even number (sum of two odds) in the tenths place becomes an odd number. That has to be even to be equal to zero mod 10. So you need multiples of four to make the tenths place even again

Answer (score 2):

Adding an odd number of coins results in a $5$ in the hundreds place. So to get $0$ in the hundreds place, you need an even number of coins.

Adding any pair of coins results in an odd number in the tens place. So to get a $0$ in the tens place, you need an even number of pairs. That is, the number of coins must be a multiple of $4$.